# If $C(c,-)$ maps all morphisms to isomorphisms, what can we say about $c$?

Tags: category-theory

Can anyone provide examples, insight, or literature on objects $c$ in a category $C$ where $C(c,-)$ maps all morphisms to isomorphisms?

Another way to say the same thing is that $c$ is left orthogonal to every morphisms in $C$, i.e. for any $v \colon c \to b$ and $f\colon a \to b$ there exists a unique lift $u \colon c \to a$ with $fu = v$.

The only simple examples I can think of are objects which are initial, or merely initial in their connected component. A more complicated example, which prompted the question, is that for any functor $T : A \to B$, a $T$-generic morphism with domain $d$ is precisely an object with this property in the category $d \downarrow T$.

Comment: Another simple example is when $C$ is a groupoid, or more generally when the connected component of $c$ is a groupoid.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is not specific enough to get good answers. What, specifically, do you want to know about these objects?

Comment: Here are some questions one might ask:
1) Do these objects already have a name in the literature and where are they studied? (reference request)
2) How to classify these objects in category X / categories of type T? (Insert specific choices for X,T.)
3) Let F : C -> D be a functor which satisfies property T. Does F preserve these objects?
4) Does every such object have property T?
5) Define the object X by ... Does it have the property?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I agree the question is vague, and perhaps not appropriate here. There's no specific property of these objects I wan't to establish. I'm just looking for other perspectives on these objects that might tie them to something I'm already familiar with or characterise them in a more 'useful' way. There's no guarantee good answers exist, but a lack of good answers is interesting too.

Comment: Fair enough. $\phantom{---}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are [*local objects*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+object). I have once searched for reference about them and quickly gave up as I have found nothing usable, only the nLab page. Therefore I will rather provide the insight and examples you have also asked for:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $J\subset\operatorname{Ar}\mathcal{C}$ be a class of morphisms, then:

**Definition** ($J$-local object): An object $c\in\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal{C}$, for which $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,c)\colon\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$ maps all morphisms in $J$ to isomorphisms (bijections), is a *$J$-local object*.

**Definition** ($J$-local morphism): A morphism $f\in\operatorname{Ar}\mathcal{C}$, for which $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{C}(f,c)$ is an isomorphism (bijection) for all $J$-local objects $c\in\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal{C}$, is a *$J$-local morphism*.

To give a few results: Immediatly from the definitions, we have:

**Corollary**: Every morphism in $J$ is a $J$-local morphism.

**Corollary**: Every isomorphism is a $J$-local morphism.

Since limits preserve isomorphisms, we have:

**Lemma**: Limits preserve $J$-local objects and colimits preserve $J$-local morphisms.

Since bijections fulfill the two-out-of-three property, we have:

**Lemma**: $J$-local morphism fulfill the two-out-of-three property.

**Corollary**: Together with the class of $J$-local morphisms, $\mathcal{C}$ is a [category with weak equivalences](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+with+weak+equivalences).

Comment: There is a $J$-local morphism to any $J$-local object from any object connected to the $J$-local object by $J$-local morphisms. Moreover, any $J$-local morphism out of a $J$-local object has a retraction, so any $J$-local morphism between $J$-local objects is an isomorphism. Thus each connected component of the wide subcategory of $J$-local morphisms contains at most one $J$-local object up to isomorphism. Moreover, the $J$-local morphisms, if any, from an object to a $J$-local object are a torsor for the post-composition action of the group of $J$-local automorphism of the $J$-local object.

Comment: Thanks, that are some nice lemmata! Have you just concluded them for yourself or found them elsewhere?

Comment: Didn't read them anywhere: just used the definition to see why the only easy examples involve initial objects in connected components.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have a (good) answer to the question, but only a slight observation.

**Recall.**
Given any object $c$ in a category $C$, the set $G ≔ C(c, c)$ becomes a monoid via composition of endomorphisms.
For every object $d$ of $C$, the set $C(c, d)$ is then a right $G$-set via precomposition.
If $f \colon d \to e$ is a morphism in $C$, then the induced map $f_* \colon C(c, d) \to C(c, e)$ is a homomorphism of right $G$-sets.

---

Let us now consider the given situation.

For every element $g$ of $G$, the left-multiplication map $g_* \colon G \to G$ is bijective.
Therefore:

1. $G = C(c, c)$ is a group.

If there exists a morphism between two objects $d$ and $e$ of $C$, then $C(c, d)$ in non-empty if and only if $C(c, e)$ is non-empty.
For every object $d$ in the connected component of $c$, the set $C(c, d)$ is therefore non-empty.
In other words, there exists an element $f$ in $C(c, d)$.
The map $f_* \colon G \to C(c, d)$ is an isomorphism of right $G$-sets.
Therefore:

2. For every object $d$ in the connected component of $c$, we have $C(c, d) ≅ G$ is right $G$-sets.

---

The combination of conditions 1 and 2 is in fact equivalent to $C(c, -)$ mapping morphisms to isomorphisms.
Indeed, suppose conversely that the object $c$ satisfies conditions 1 and 2.
Let $f \colon d \to e$ be an arbitrary morphism in $C$.
We have two cases to consider:

- If both $d$ and $e$ are outside the connected component of $c$, then both $C(c, d)$ and $C(c, e)$ are empty.
  Consequently, $f_* \colon C(c, d) \to C(c, e)$ is bijective.
- If both $d$ and $e$ are contained in the connected component of $c$, then by condition 1, both $C(c, d)$ and $C(c, e)$ are isomorphic to $G$ as right $G$-sets.
  The composite
  $$
    G ≅ C(c, d) \xrightarrow{\enspace f^* \enspace} C(c, e) ≅ G
  $$
  is a homomorphism of right $G$-sets.
  But every homomorphism of right $G$-sets $G \to G$ is given by left-multiplication with some element of $G$, and therefore bijective by condition 2.
  Consequently, $f_* \colon C(c, d) \to C(c, e)$ was bijective to begin with.